# Error in running Electron CLI in Ubuntu-18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, electron, ubuntu-18.04, linux-mint

As I installed electron 8.2 successfully on my linux, I encountered this error while I ran the cli command:

```
electron .
```

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/index.js:14
>       throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again')
>       ^
>
> Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete
>   node_modules/electron and try installing again
>       at getElectronPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/index.js:14:11)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/index.js:18:18)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/cli.js:3:16)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the problem is with the usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron folder.
It seemed installed improperly.
So, I copied the node_modules/electron/dist folder in local project and pasted in the global folder mentioned above and :
wooooooooohoooooooooo!!!! solved